# Numpy matrix inverse appears to use multiple threads

Tags: python, numpy

So I have this really simple code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

mat = np.identity(4)
for i in range (100000):
    np.linalg.inv(mat)

for i in range (100000):
    sp.linalg.inv(mat)
```

Now, the first bit where the inverse is done through numpy, for some reason, launches 3 additional threads (so 4 total, including the main) and collectively they consume roughly 3 or my available cores, causing the fans on my computer to go wild.

The second bit where I use Scipy has no noticable impact on CPU use and there's only one thread, the main thread. This runs about 20% slower than the numpy loop.

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Is numpy doing threading in the background? Why is it so inefficient?

Comment: numpy and scipy use different lapack  functions for  calculation of the `inv`-function. Whether those functions are threaded depends on the LAPACK-implementation your installation is using. You cannot expect to gain much from parallelization for 4x4 matrices. Compare the performance for let's say 4000x4000 matrices (you will also probably see that scipy's version is also parallelized)

Comment: I understand that much as well as why the inverse happening in parallel doesn't gain much and that the CPU is busy probably just dealing with overheads.  I guess what I don't understand is why there isn't a case in numpy to not use the parallel implementation under a certain matrix size

Comment: Using parallelization is not a decision numpy/scipy are making, but the lapack functions which are used by numpy/scipy. As to asking why somebody doesn't spend their time to optimize a function for a 4x4 matrix.... well, they have probably a bigger fish to fry.

Comment: Also, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html explicitly states (first paragraph) that `threadpoolctl` may be needed to control the number of threads or specify the processor architecture.

Comment: Thank you Davide that's very helpful. I'll read up more on that.

Comment: FWIW my numpy-installation doesn't use parallelization for 4x4 matrices, but does so for e.g. 400x400. You can see here https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L551 and here https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L1622 that this choice isn't done by the numpy (must also be done by the used lapack-implementation).

Comment: Interesting. The only reason this even came up for me was because I wrote some code that needed to invert a transformation matrix at 40hz (it's no longer using inversion now and doing it a different way) and the overall process is pretty heavy. I was trying to profile it and realized that most of what was making my computer sweat as the matrix inverse. Not the 10000x10000 linear system I was solving or the large laser scans I was fitting to one another, nope... just a 4x4 matrix inverse.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, the fix was to set `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` and then run the python script in the same terminal.

My issue was that a simple code block that consists of `np.linalg.inv()` was consuming more than 50% of CPU usage. After setting the OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS parameter, the CPU usage dropped to around 3% and also the total execution time reduced. I read somewhere that this is an issue with the OPENBLAS library (Which is used by numpy.linalg.inv function). Hope this helps!